# NSUsernotification response returns nil sometimes

Tags: android, ios, macos, swift3

I am creating an application where I am reflecting my Android notifications on mac and reply to them from mac itself. I am using `NSUsernotification` to do the same. Notifications work perfectly. When I click on reply button and type in text, sometimes `notification.response` returns `nil` in `didActive notification` delegate. Can anyone help me with that?

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: NSUserNotificationCenter, didActivate notification: NSUserNotification) {
    if notification.activationType == NSUserNotification.ActivationType.replied {
        print(notification.response) //This is nil sometimes. Not always
    }
}
```

Comment: No one facing this issue?